# OpenJson store processed object in original form

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, open-json

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
{
"OrderNumber":"SO43659",
"OrderDate":"2011-05-31T00:00:00",
"AccountNumber":"AW29825",
"ItemPrice":2024.9940,
"ItemQuantity":1
},
{
"OrderNumber":"SO43661",
"OrderDate":"2011-06-01T00:00:00",
"AccountNumber":"AW73565",
"ItemPrice":2024.9940,
"ItemQuantity":3
}
]'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @JSON)  
WITH (   
            OrderNumber   VARCHAR(200)  ,  
            OrderDate     VARCHAR(200)      ,  
            AccountNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)  ,  
            ItemPrice NVARCHAR(MAX)            ,  
            ItemQuantity NVARCHAR(MAX)     ,
            OriginalObject NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSOn       
 )
```

I want to store processed object i.e each json object  in its original form in OriginalObject table column.

[image]

I have done quite bit searching but did not find any solution.

I want to store original json object so that no need to convert it row to json as its increases performance problem.i get orignal data using above column.

**version of sql server:Microsoft SQL Server 2017** (RTM-CU21) (KB4557397) - 14.0.3335.7 (X64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` without a schema to break out the array into single objects, then `APPLY` again the `OPENJSON` function to get the full schema.

```sql
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
{
"OrderNumber":"SO43659",
"OrderDate":"2011-05-31T00:00:00",
"AccountNumber":"AW29825",
"ItemPrice":2024.9940,
"ItemQuantity":1
},
{
"OrderNumber":"SO43661",
"OrderDate":"2011-06-01T00:00:00",
"AccountNumber":"AW73565",
"ItemPrice":2024.9940,
"ItemQuantity":3
}
]';

SELECT
  o.*,
  array.value AS OriginalObject
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) array
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(array.value)
  WITH (   
    OrderNumber   varchar(200),  
    OrderDate     datetime,
    AccountNumber varchar(50),
    ItemPrice     decimal(18,9),  
    ItemQuantity  int
 ) o;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95c3bbde40dfdf2d8ee35bc39ef47768)

> I suggest you choose your data types more carefully.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. for you help. this is demo json because of confidentiality i cannot share original data. i have managed to merge that with you solution. thanks a lot for your help.